# How to move a subdomain in blogger to wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, web, blogs, blogger

I have a website that is hosted in [Blogger](http://www.blogger.com/) with a custom domain. I also had a subdomain that used a different theme than the main website. Now I want to move to [WordPress](http://wordpress.org). I got a wordpress hosting from GoDaddy and used the installation wizard to install WordPress. Now, there is step during the installation that asks for the domain for the website. What I want is that my domain should remain in Blogger, but subdomain should be in wordpress. Is this possible?

Or, even if I move my main domain to wordpress, still  is it possible to have a subdomain in wordpress with another template. I am a newbie to WordPress.

Comment: When it asks you for your domain, it's so it can set the value of `site_url()` and `home_url()` in the database, so it knows how to create your permalinks and serve your asset data. It does not effectively indicate that your sub domain will point there automatically. A subdomain can have an `A` record created to point wherever given that you can access your nameservers.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So, what exactly i need to enter there. Entering the subdomain gives error. Atleast can you guide me in setting up a subdomain in wordpress witha different theme.

Comment: I've never used an auto installer there so for it to indicate that you must use a domain that doesn't have a subdomain prefix is very odd to me. I'm uncertain how to guide you further in that respect. Well, I take that back. you could always use your primary domain, then adjust those two values I mentioned earlier in your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Follow these steps:

1) Go to database and choose wp_option table. Change site_url whatever you want in wordpress.

2) Go to "General" in setting option in admin panel and change both url given in box.

that's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the subdomain should work with WordPress site, then you just need to point CNAME or A record to Godaddy hosting account and the subdomain site will be live with WordPress.